# FastAPI pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: <exception str() failed>

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I have a simple test in my FastAPI application, when I run it with pytest (`python -m pytest app`), I get this error

`pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: <unprintable ValidationError object>`

The test file:

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

def test_health_check():
    """
    Test the GET health check
    """
    client = TestClient(app)
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I have `fastapi==0.92.0` and `pydantic==1.10.11`, this error started to happen when I upgraded FastAPI from 0.79.0 to 0.92.0

I would like to post the full stack trace here, but when I try to do it, stackoverflow says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.", so I will try to post in the comments.

Edit:

I can't post in the comments either because it's too long, here's a pastebin with the stack trace: https://pastebin.com/8gyF0zyv

Edit:

Here's the controller code. Indeed the error is here because it works when I return only `{"message": "Welcome"}`.

```
@app.get("/")
async def index() -> dict[str, str]:
    return {
        "message": "Welcome",
        "API": {"version": __version__, "updated": updated},
        "Common package": {"version": apicommon.__version__, "updated": apicommon.updated},
    }
```

Comment: The stack trace is too long to post in the comments, I can't post here either.

Comment: That's not usually the way we recommend, but can you share a screenshort or a pastebin link ?

Comment: Hy not upgrade to pydantic>=2 ?

Comment: @azro FastAPI requires pydantic<2.0.0

Comment: I've create a pastebin with the stack trace https://pastebin.com/8gyF0zyv

Comment: Recent versions of FastAPI works just fine with pydantic 2 - but it would be very helpful to have the code your controller is, because this is caused by your controller returning something that can't be converted the way you've described it to be.

Comment: We need to see the contents of main.py to understand where the error may be! Can you post it or a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was indeed in the controller as MatsLindh pointed out. The function return type was `dict[str, str]` and it should be `dict[str, Any]`, as it is returning also dictionaries as values of the dictionary.

```
@app.get("/")
async def index() -> dict[str, str]: # should be dict[str, Any]
    return {
        "message": "Welcome",
        "API": {"version": __version__, "updated": updated},
        "Common package": {"version": apicommon.__version__, "updated": apicommon.updated},
    }
```

FastAPI 0.79.0 was not doing this validation, but FastAPI 0.92.0 does.